# regex - Optimize up regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

Is it possible to optimize the following ruby regexp?

```
%r{(.*(?:^|\s))#{pfx}\s+#([\w\-\.:/]+)\s+(.+)}.match(line)
/[^\s]\x40todo/.match(line)
/\x40todo(?!\s+#)/.match(line)
/\x40todo\s+#\s/.match(line)
/[^\s]TODO:?/.match(line)
/TODO(?!:?\s+#)/.match(line)
/TODO:?\s+#\s/.match(line)
%r{([\w\-\.]+)(?::(\d+)(?:(m|h)[a-z]*)?)?(?:/([A-Z]+))?}.match(text)
```

Actually i suppose that
2 - 6 -> no way to optimize except possibility to use grep check if line need to call this regexp#match ??

Comment: It would help to have examples of what you're matching. Also, the final line of code is matching `text` instead of `line`. And do you only need to know whether it matches?

Answer (score 0):

The regexes could be improved, but without knowing what you're matching I can't say how. But there's two general optimizations.

1. Use [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to turn them into a single regex.
2. Use [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F) instead of `match` if you just want to know whether it matches. This avoids the overhead of making a MatchData object.